# Find derivative $f(x) = (2+\sin(x))^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Find derivative function: $$f(x) = (2+\sin(x))^{x}$$

---

My solution
$$ \frac{d }{d x} e^{(2+\sin(x))x} = e^{2+\sin(x)}(2+\sin(x)+x\cos(x))$$

To check result I am using wolfram to compute this derivative

Result from https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%2Bsin(x))%5Ex

$$ (2+\sin(x))^{x}\left(\log(2+\sin(x))+\frac{x\cos(x)}{2+\sin(x)}\right)$$

But I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: when you typed the result from wolfram, you left out a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you went wrong is you wanted $$ \frac{d }{d x} e^{\color{red}\ln(2+\sin(x))x} $$

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$\ln(f(x))=x\ln(2+\sin(x))$$ so by the chain rule we get
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln(2+\sin(x))+\frac{x}{2+\sin(x)}\cos(x)$$ so
$$f'(x)=(2+\sin(x))^x\left(\ln(2+\sin(x))+\frac{x\cos(x)}{2+\sin(x)}\right)$$